# Differentiating between the two types of nouns using spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy to understand phrases and I am trying to differentiate between Nouns like food, beer, wine etc. and other nouns like yesterday and today.

I am not able to come up with an idea as to how to differentiate them.

```py
   query = input()
   doc = nlp(query)
   displacy.serve(doc,style="dep")
```

What can I do to differentiate between the first three nouns and yesterday?
The diplacy rendering is as shown in the image
image link => https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QKaN.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you can do is to check its entity:

```
sent = "Yesterday, I drank a beer"
doc = nlp(sent)
for token in doc:
   print(token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.ent_type_) 
#Output:
#Yesterday NOUN NN DATE
#, PUNCT , 
#I PRON PRP 
#drank VERB VBD 
#a DET DT 
#beer NOUN NN
```

As you can see, dates like yesterday and today are recogniced as a date-entity. There are a few entities defined in spacy, [here is a list](https://spacy.io/api/annotation).